# Converting empty values to NULL in R - Handling date column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe as: `dput(emp)`

```
structure(list(name = structure(1L, .Label = "Alex", class = "factor"), 
    job = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), Mgr = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
    update = structure(18498, class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

I want to convert all empty rows to `NULL`

The simplest way to achieve is:

```
emp[emp==""] <- NA
```

Which ofcourse would have worked but I get the error for the date column as:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

How can I convert all other empty rows to NULL without having to deal with the date column? Please note that the actual data frame has 30000+ rows.

Comment: I'm going to be really pedantic here, but please note that `NULL` and `NA` are VERY different concepts in R. The various types of `NA` represent missing values and can be elements of an atomic vector of the corresponding type that has a length attribute. NULL is an undefined value and cannot be a member of an atomic vector. While you could convert data.frame records to `NULL`, any solution that does this will have to convert any atomic vector column receiving a `NULL` to `list` type and this will cause the resulting `data.frame` to be much harder to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try formating the date variable as character, make the change and transform to date again:

```
#Format date
emp$update <- as.character(emp$update)
#Replace
emp[emp=='']<-NA
#Reformat date
emp$update <- as.Date(emp$update)
```

Output:

```
  name  job  Mgr     update
1 Alex <NA> <NA> 2020-08-24
```

Comment: thnx. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `type.convert` like below

```
type.convert(emp,as.is = TRUE)
```

such that

```
  name job Mgr     update
1 Alex  NA  NA 2020-08-24
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(update),as.character) %>%
  na_if(.,"")
```

As mentioned by @Duck, you have to format the `date` variable as character.

afterwards you can transform it back to `date` if you need it:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(update),as.character) %>%
  na_if(.,"") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(update),as.Date)
```

Comment: You could also use `na_if("")` instad of `na_if( . ,"")`

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(purrr)
> emp <- structure(list(name = structure(1L, .Label = "Alex", class = "factor"), 
+                      job = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), Mgr = structure(1L, .Label = "", class = "factor"), 
+                      update = structure(18498, class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
+                                                                                                      -1L))
> emp
  name job Mgr     update
1 Alex         2020-08-24
> emp %>% mutate(update = as.character(update)) %>% map_df(~gsub('^$',NA, .x)) %>% mutate(update = as.Date(update)) %>% mutate(across(1:3, as.factor))
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  name  job   Mgr   update    
  <fct> <fct> <fct> <date>    
1 Alex  NA    NA    2020-08-24
>
```